# Absurdly high difference between buy and sell rates between Swedish crowns and Russian rubles

Tags: foreign-exchange, russia

I came across the following pretty surprising exchange rates at a Russian bank between Swedish crowns and Russian rubles (https://www.tinkoff.ru/about/exchange/, in Russian):

- 1118.491 rubles when buying 1 crown
- 0.0008940617 rubles when selling 1 crown

Of course, at the moment the markets are very disturbed due to the war in Ukraine, but still, how come the buy and sell rates are so drastically different? Aren’t they supposed to be at least in the same order of magnitude? As a comparison, the corresponding numbers for the euro are still somewhat more reasonable at 111.5 and 100.7, and for Swedish crowns they are usually both somewhere around 10.

I’m really confused. If Swedish crowns are hard to get by, which might very well be the case due to the financial sanctions, shouldn’t both exchange rates be pretty high? Why is one super high and the other one super low. Or is it just that the bank really doesn’t want to have anything to do with Swedish crowns at the moment?

Here are two screenshots, as it will probably change soon.
[image: Exchange rate for Swedish crowns]
[image: Exchange rate for euros]

Comment: Note that 1/0.00008940617 = 1118.491 so I think you are just misunderstanding which way round the numbers are being quoted. But then I can't explain why there appears to be no spread for Swedish crowns and there is a spread for Euros.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, but I have access to a bank account there and trying to exchange money in the app is consistent with my interpretation. It takes a thousand rubles to obtain one crown, and a thousand crowns to obtain one ruble. Also the numbers are back to normal now, so I guess it was just a bug (???)

Comment: More likely noone wants to make a deal involving roubles. Who wants more roubles ?

Comment: @mmmmmm "Who wants more roubles ?" Answered [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/110962/64920).

Comment: @nanoman from that answer note " If the economy is growing, it may make more sense from an investment standpoint as well. If it is shrinking then maybe not."  so not really an answer. Anyway more uncertainty also will make people less likely to want to buy, and the lender of last resort Russia's central Bank is blocked in many cases

Comment: @mmmmmm Then how do you explain the non-crazy rates in euros? Or the fact that it's now back to being in the same order of magnitude? Or the fact that they were exactly inverse to each other despite being expressed in the same unit? Also there were similar super weird rates exchanging Russian rubles with Belarusian rubles. A bug is I guess the only possible explanation.

Comment: Exchange rates are like stock quotes: they just reflect the last transaction. Maybe someone with roubles absolutely, positively had to exchange them for crowns *now*, and the only available option was someone that had jacked up the price.  (More likely, someone with *lots* of roubles bought crowns from anyone currently offering them, saturated the more "normal" sellers, and ended up buying from some lucky person who had offered an exorbitant price without really expecting anyone would take them up on it.)